# Save dataframe to file in shinyTable

Tags: r, shiny

I load a csv file as data frame in a shinyTable. How can I add a button which saves changed edits in the shinyTable?

Here are the current files

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  cachedTbl <- NULL

  output$tbl <- renderHtable({
    if (is.null(input$tbl)){

      setwd("~/projects/shinyTable")
      datafile <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", quote="")
      tbl <- datafile

      cachedTbl <<- tbl
      print(tbl)
      return(tbl)
    } else{
      cachedTbl <<- input$tbl
      print(input$tbl)
      return(input$tbl)
    }
  })  
})
```

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Simple Shiny Table!"),

  sidebarPanel(
    helpText(HTML("A simple editable matrix.
                  <p>Created using <a href = \"http://github.com/trestletech/shinyTable\">shinyTable</a>."))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    htable("tbl", colHeaders="provided"),
    actionButton("actionButtonID","update data file")
  )
))
```

I added the button, but so far it has no functionality. In a later iteration I also want to add a side menu with fields which allows to add a new line to the data frame (which can also saved to the csv file).

Any ideas how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved a similar thing with an app I've made. I did it by creating a function to save the data. I'm assuming tbl is a new line of data to be added to the existing csv "data.csv", is that right?

So create a function, something like:

```
saveData <- function( tbl ) {
    setwd("~/projects/shinyTable")
    datafile <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", quote="")
    datafile <- rbind( datafile, tbl )
    write.csv( datafile, file = "data.csv" )
}
```

Then activate that function on a button press, using an observeEvent to detect it:

```
observeEvent( input$actionButtonID, {
    saveData( input$tbl )
}
```

I haven't used htable before, so I'm not sure about the data call "input$tbl", but it seems to me like that should work.

Can you arrange that into your app?

Comment: It's a good idea to also reset the values in your htable, to make it obvious to a user that their data has gone through. I don't know how to do that with an htable, sorry. I use commands like "updateNumericInput(...)", but I don't know of the equivalent for htable.